# Retrofit map json variable to keyword

Tags: android, gson, retrofit

So I'm working with retrofit with an API that has a variable called "public". How would I go about getting it to automatically map like all the other variables do.

Example:

```
@GET("/?filter=my_images")
void getMyImages(
        @Query("client_id") String id,
        @Query("api_key") String key,
        Callback<ImageList> callback
);
public static class Image{
    int id;
    String name;
    String distribution;
    String slug;
    // Can't do this:
    boolean public;
}

public static class ImageList{
    String status;
    List<Image> images;
}
```

Example API results (json):

```
{
  "status": "OK",
  "images": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "My first snapshot",
      "distribution": "Ubuntu",
      "slug": "ubuntu-12.10-x32",
      "public": true
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "Automated Backup",
      "distribution": "Ubuntu"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Retrofit uses Gson for serialization to and from JSON.

Gson provides a `@SerializedName` annotation in order to change the key to which a field or method is mapped. You can use this for handling your reserved word:

```
@SerializedName("public")
public String isPublic;
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. I'm new to dealing with annotations, so I forget to check out things like that. That'll also help to get rid of those ugly nonstandard variables with underscores.

Comment: @JaySee you might also have a look at `setFieldNamingPolicy`/`setFieldNamingStrategy` options when creating your `GsonConverter` - these can be used to automatically map underscored JSON to camel-cased properties names (and vice-versa)

Comment: Hi Jake, can somebody from Square give some hints on this question please: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24467416/retrofit-cache-control-never-included-in-response ?

Answer (score 0):

Please look at this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2370745/convert-json-style-properties-names-to-java-camelcase-names-with-gson/11810183#11810183), which is a neater solution if there are underscores in each key.