# Change JSON key without changing variable name in POJO

Tags: java, json, jackson, gson

I have a class definition say

```
class Employee {
 String id;
 String name;
 int age;
 //getters and setters
}
```

I want to create a json object out of it as follows

```
{
  "id" : "A12",
  "employee_name" : "Abhishek"
  age : 97
}
```

Notice that `employee_name` does not correspond to POJO variable `name`. So can I add certain annotation which will help me do so ? Something Like

```
@JSONKey(value="employee_name")
String name
```

Give solutions related to GSON and/or Jackson.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In `Jackson` use `@JsonProperty`

E.g.:

```
@JsonProperty(value="employee_name")
String name
```

with `GSON` use  `@SerializedName`

```
@SerializedName(value="employee_name")
String name
```

Comment: You saved my time bro, thanks a lot. I was using @JsonProperty for GSON, I didn't realize I was using the wrong implantation. I used @SerializedName("jsonFieldName") for GSON and It solved my problem. Thansk again.

Answer (score 0):

With Gson you can use the @SerializedName annotation

```
@SerializedName("employee_name")
String name;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `@JsonProperty` for Jackson: [Change field name in JSON using Jackson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7263282/change-field-name-in-json-using-jackson)

And `@SerializedName` for Gson: [Convert JSON style properties names to Java CamelCase names with GSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2370745/convert-json-style-properties-names-to-java-camelcase-names-with-gson)